How to promote code to different environments in GitFlow branching strategy
I am a one person team of my project.
I have adopted GitFlow branching strategy for my project which I have read from here, excluding the release branches because I am the the only developer in the team and release branches are created from develop and merges to main, so I merge the develop to main branch directly.
So basically this is what I have

Main branch - I have a main branch which has the production code at any given time.
Develop branch - The develop branch which will get all the feature branches merged into and once everything is ready to be released then this branch will be merged to the main branch.
Feature branches - Feature branches are created from develop branch and when the feature is completed they are merged to develop.

Everything works fine till the development is going.
The question arises when I have to test the code in different environments. These are the environments I have for my project testing

dev - Where I first deploy the code to do a sanity testing. Kind of a playground for me. Once I am satisfied I will want to code to be promoted to stage.
stage - This environment is supposed to be tested by a tester. Once the testing is done with all the bug fixes the code should be promoted to the uat environment.
uat - This is the environment where client will be testing the application. Once client gives go ahead (may need to fix some bugs here as well) then the develop will be merged to main branch and the code will go to production.

Now the question is how should I promote code to different environments because I only have develop branch and everywhere I find that having branches per environment is wrong idea and we should not mix branching strategy with environments.
So what should be the strategy for the code promotion in GitFlow branching strategy?
How do others who use GitFlow branching strategy solve this problem?

you dont, you separate your deployments from your builds. then you can deploy a build multiple times to multiple environments

Decoupling branching and deployment
In git, every commit has a unique hash, branches and basic tags simply point to a commit hash, hence it is reasonable to develop environment deployment script(s) which take two parameters: The commit hash to deploy and the name of the environment.
Doing this decouples your branching and deployment strategies:

If you want to you can deploy the same commit to multiple environments.
You can choose to manually deploy a particular commit to an environment.
You can add a (commit) hook so that a commit to a particular branch triggers a deployment to a particular environment.

Number of Environments
Generally most projects have two phases:

Parallel development - where multiple developers (or teams) are working on multiple features concurrently - during this phase it is often unclear which team is going to be done first / ready to release.
Serialized development - some set of features is "anointed" as being ready to go, so they are grouped/packaged together in some way and start moving through a set of testing environments on their way to production.

Typically the number of "useful" environments is dependent on these two phases - if you have a lot of developers it can be helpful to have multiple environments to stop them stepping on each other. If you have a very long/slow testing process more environments may be necessary to support that.
Branching Strategies
Are just a form of bookkeeping:

What's currently in flight
What's changes are being grouped together.
What order/when were things deployed.

Generally speaking if you have a small number of developers and environments your branching strategy doesn't need to be particularly complex. If the project has a lot of concurrent development (due to larger number of devs and environments) then more complex branching strategies may be necessary.
Single Dev
Frankly I doubt you need GitFlow as a single dev - you will just be conducting a bunch of ceremonies for the sake of doing them - it probably won't give you any real advantage.
However if you insist of following it, you can probably just add commit hooks to your develop and main branches to trigger deployments to your dev and production environments respectively. Then manually trigger deployments to the other environments as you need them (based on a commit hash).
Additional Questions (from comments)

what strategy do you suggest?

As a solo dev - whatever works for you, my main point was to decouple deployment and branching strategy, so that you can change branching strategy when you need to.
For solo projects, I typically find I only need my laptop (local) a single pre-prod environment (lets call it staging) and a production environment. I typically just use a single main branch with two additional branches for staging and prod. So if you look at my repo you will see three branches on a linear history, with main being the most current, staging a bit behind and prod the oldest
This is just a super lightweight deploy strategy, until I need something more complex.
I typically automate my deployments and tie them to a branch, so that all I need to do to deploy is push (to origin) that branch and the deploy starts.
There are some flaws with this simple approach, but on balance I am okay with them (overall its less work dealing with the problems than a doing the ceremonies of a more complex approach) - if you feel differently then add some additional steps to your process.

I need to know or kind of have some identification that this commit 12345 is tested successfully on qa

There are two parts to that question.
Was the test successful?
Given your timeline (months) for testing, I am going to assume that this is manual testing or at least manual sign off. You could automate this (add a branch or tag to git), but with only a few sign-offs per year I doubt its worth the effort (over the alternative of getting a green light in an email).
What version was tested?
I will keep this simple, have your deployment script write a small file during the deployment containing, some combination of:

The commit hash being deployed.
Start time of the deployment.
End time of the deployment.
Status - was the deploy successful.
List of deployment errors (if any)

If your app is a web app, you can place this file somewhere under the web root such that a tester can remotely view the file contents simply by hitting a particular URL.
Then when they send you an email saying that they have completed testing (successfully) they can cut-and-paste the commit hash to you.
You could also update a tag or branch in git during the deploy script, however realistically that is only really for you / only has value if you find it useful (given you can hit the URL too - and get a confirmation that the deploy was successful).
Flaws
In my previous answers I had note "There are some flaws", the biggest flaw is that I have assumed that deployment is simply pushing the code somewhere. I.e. that there is no build (compile) or package step, note packaging could be of several types, for example: Zip file, an assembly, a docker image or an entire VM image.
Typically all build and packaging steps have some additional dependencies that get included, direct dependencies, transitive dependencies, compiler versions, libraries on the build system, etc.
So it can be difficult to say with 100% certainty that if you rebuild/repackage a particular commit hash, you will get exactly the same output package (ideally an identical file). Therefore a common practice is not to rebuild from source, instead deploy the final package (typically a docker or VM image) to the next environment.
There are many approaches that can achieve this, but one of the simpler ones is to separate the build and deploy steps, such that you only build a package once (for a given commit hash) and then upload the binary (docker image, etc) to a repository. If you later need to deploy that hash to a different environment you first check if the build already exists (and use it) so that you can know for sure you are deploying exactly the same binary to the next environment.
Additional Questions (Round 2)
I am tempted to say, "just do what you want", in that if something isn't working for you, you can just change to something else - there is no-one else you need to get buy in from, to make the change.
However, I will take a stab at your questions:

Should I merge the code from one environment to another when it passes the current environment testing, right? So when the code passes develop, I should merge the code from develop to qa branch, ...

I don't like the word merge in your statement.
I use "environment branches" - Git branches that are named similar to the environments, with a hook that deploys to the environment. However I don't ever merge, rebase or commit to these branches - I just use my favorite Git GUI and drag the branch tag to the relevant commit and do a push to origin. **
So in your example I would just drag the qa tag to the same commit as develop was currently pointing to and "Push to Origin".
This is a mental switch - I don't view these "environment branches" as real branches (where work is done), they are just a hack so that I don't have to go to a web page somewhere and enter a git hash and hit deploy.
** - To anticipate others responses, I realize that I should consider CI, however per the text above I only have 3 environments:

Local/Laptop - where I do all my development and testing.
Staging - Which is really just a demo / final test environment.
Production

So I manually sign off deployments to either staging or production.

So as per your suggested approach I should have develop,stage,uat and main (for prod) branches, and each branch will be deployed to each environment, right?

I don't like using main for this purpose as I get pretty fast and lose dragging the prod tag around (and some repo's are configured to protect the main branch - so I can't do that), but again your repo your call.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I have two follow up questions - First, if I should not be using GitFlow for single dev, what strategy do you suggest? Second - Yes, I will promote the code from develop only  to the next environments when the testing completes for an environment, but how will I know till which environment the code is tested? Are you suggesting I should add tags for each testing complete like dev-tested, qa-tested to know the next environment to promote the code to? Because it is always going to be the same commit of develop branch getting tested to all environments

So for example if develop branch commit 12345 is deployed to dev environment and I tested it and it works fine, I will want to promote the same commit to the next environment qa and then the qa passes it I will have to promote the same commit to uat environment so at each testing complete cycle I need to know or kind of have some identification that this commit 12345 is tested successfully on qa for example, so even if I come back after a month I know that the code should go to uat now . Tags look easiest solution, but do you suggest them or is there any better alternative?

@PawanNogariya, those might be good topics for additional posts. Just be sure to limit each post to a single question.

@GregBurghardt - Actually that was basically what I wanted to ask in my original question, but I might not be clear, I will post the another question. Thanks

@DavidT - Thank you for updating the answer for my follow up questions. The approach that you suggested sounds quite good and actually I also wanted to go something like that way, so for my case I have development,stage, uat and production environments. So as per your suggested approach I should have develop,stage,uat and main (for prod) branches, and each branch will be deployed to each environment, right? Actually I really wanted to do like that but I have learnt everywhere that it is not recommended to have branches for each environment, your thoughts?

@DavidT - Also, if I go with that approach I should merge the code from one environment to another when it passes the current environment testing, right? So when the code passes develop, I should merge the code from develop to qa branch, then from qa to uat branch and so.. on.. Am I thinking correctly here?
